# C# DatagridView shows 0 columns

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm creating a DataGridView and using a DataTable to populate it.

**My C#**

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Col_1");
dt.Columns.Add("Col_2");

for(int i=0; i< myDictionary; i++)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(myDictionary.key, myDictionary.Value);
}

dgv.DataSource = dt;

for(int j=0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
{...} // this is where Count is always 0...
```

I'm really just looking to access the columns so that I can do something like

`dgv.Columns[j].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;`

Q: How can have the dataGridView reflect the columns properly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property `AutogenerateColumns` to `true`:

```
dgv.AutogenerateColumns = true;
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I'm still not seeing any columns in the dgv

Comment: are you using Winforms right?

Comment: yes i am; and i think that AutoGenerateColumns is default to true. in debugger, i see the value is true without assigning it

Comment: the DataTable has data?

Comment: yes, If I run my code, i see the table with data, it's just that the width of the columns doesn't span the table

Comment: Do you call DataBind() after setting DataSource?